Manual Calculation using STL Decomposition
Does anyone know how to manually perform calculations using STL Decomposition? I have this data:



Date
Count




2017-01-31
68


2017-02-28
59


2017-03-31
75


2017-04-30
71


2017-05-31
70


2017-06-30
68


2017-07-31
73


2017-08-31
87


2017-09-30
69


2017-10-31
74


2017-11-30
83


2017-12-31
91


2018-01-31
53


2018-02-28
61


2018-03-31
73


2018-04-30
63


2018-05-31
52


2018-06-30
52


2018-07-31
71


2018-08-31
76


2018-09-30
66


2018-10-31
62


2018-11-30
48


2018-12-31
99


2019-01-31
60


2019-02-28
76


2019-03-31
71


2019-04-30
73


2019-05-31
56


2019-06-30
70


2019-07-31
73


2019-08-31
85


2019-09-30
65


2019-10-31
74


2019-11-30
73


2019-12-31
78


2020-01-31
69


2020-02-29
54


2020-03-31
32


2020-04-30
10


2020-05-31
10


2020-06-30
10


2020-07-31
10


2020-08-31
10


2020-09-30
10


2020-10-31
10


2020-11-30
10


2020-12-31
10


2021-01-31
10


2021-02-28
10


2021-03-31
10


2021-04-30
10


2021-05-31
10


2021-06-30
10


2021-07-31
10


2021-08-31
10


2021-09-30
10


2021-10-31
10


2021-11-30
10


2021-12-31
10


2022-01-31
10


2022-02-28
10


2022-03-31
10


2022-04-30
11


2022-05-31
21


2022-06-30
25


2022-07-31
31


2022-08-31
39


2022-09-30
27


2022-10-31
42


2022-11-30
40


2022-12-31
64


2023-01-31
50


2023-02-28
53


2023-03-31
56


2023-04-30
56


2023-05-31
57


2023-06-30
57


2023-07-31
60


2023-08-31
69


2023-09-30
55


2023-10-31
50



Please help me get the results from manual STL Decomposition calculations along with the formulas used. It doesn't have to be all of it, because what I need is the usage of formulas and the workflow until obtaining the Seasonal, Trend, Residual, and Deseasonalized components. The period used for this manual calculation is every 12 months. I have steps for performing STL Decomposition, which are roughly like this:

The original time series is subtracted by the initial trend estimate (a constant value) to produce the de-trended time series.
$$ x_t - \hat{T}_0 = x_t - \mu $$

The de-trended time series is divided into ( k ) subseries and smoothed using LOESS with ( q ) neighboring observations, resulting in the smoothed subseries values (( \hat{s}_{it} )).
$$ \hat{s}_{it} = \text{LOESS}(x_{it}, t_i, q) $$
where,

( \hat{s}_{it} ): Estimate of subseries value ( i ) at period ( t_i )
( x_{it} ): Subseries observation value ( i ) at period ( t_i )
LOESS: LOESS regression function (Local Regression)
( t_i ): Time (period) of subseries ( i )
( q ): Number of neighboring observations used in LOESS regression


The smoothed subseries are extrapolated for ( 2k ) out-of-sample observations.

The smoothed subseries are filtered using several self-determined moving averages (MA) and LOESS with one neighboring observation, resulting in the initial seasonal component (( \hat{m}_t )).
$$ \hat{m}_t = \text{MA}(t) \circ \text{LOESS}(\hat{s}_t, t, l) $$
where,

( \hat{m}_t ): Estimate of initial seasonal component at period ( t )
MA(( t )): Moving average at period ( t )
( \circ ): Composition operator
LOESS(( \hat{s}_t, t, l )): LOESS regression function (Local Regression)
( \hat{s}_t ): Smoothed subseries value at period ( t )
( t ): Time (period) of the subseries
( l ): Number of neighboring observations used in LOESS regression


The initial seasonal component is subtracted from the filtered seasonal component to produce the final seasonal component (( \hat{c}_t )).

The de-trended time series is subtracted by the final seasonal component to produce the seasonally adjusted time series.
$$ x_t - \hat{T}_0 - \hat{c}_t = x_t - \mu - \hat{c}_t $$

The seasonally adjusted time series is smoothed using LOESS with ( t ) neighboring observations, resulting in the trend component (( \hat{T}_t )).
$$ \hat{T}_t = \text{LOESS}(x_t - \hat{\mu} - \hat{c}_t, t, t) $$
where,

( \hat{T}_t ): Estimate of the trend component at period ( t )
LOESS(( x_t - \hat{\mu} - \hat{c}_t, t, t )): LOESS regression function (Local Regression)
( x_t ): Original time series observation value at period ( t )
( \hat{\mu} ): Estimate of the time series mean value
( \hat{c}_t ): Estimate of the seasonal component at period ( t )
( t ): Time (period) of the time series


The original time series is subtracted by the final seasonal component and the trend component to produce the irregular component (( \hat{R}_t )).
$$ \hat{R}_t = x_t - \hat{\mu} - \hat{c}_t - \hat{T}_t $$
where,

( \hat{R}_t ): Estimate of the irregular component at period ( t )
( x_t ): Original time series observation value at period ( t )
( \hat{\mu} ): Estimate of the time series mean value
( \hat{c}_t ): Estimate of the seasonal component at period ( t )
( \hat{T}_t ): Estimate of the trend component at period ( t )
( t ): Time (period) of the time series


Outlier-based weights are assigned from the irregular component.

Outlier-based weights are reused in the subsequent steps, repeating again from step 1.


Please also check if the steps are correct or incorrect like this.

Nobody, ever in the history of statistics, has performed a LOESS calculation manually, nor would they want to.  The reason is that it requires multiple least-squares fits over moving windows.  What, then, are you really trying to ask?

Manually calculate the STL Decomposition from this data. It’s okay to use only a small segment of the data. The important thing is that I understand the use of the formulas, the flow, and the results obtained. The data I use is only a reduction of the original values. Speaking of the original values, here is the form of what I worked on using Python Pandas:
https://www.overleaf.com/6958674565qrxvjdffxpjj#a74eed
I already completed it using Python Pandas, but my Lecturer asked for a manual calculation of STL using dummy data, and And I need to present the manual calculation to her.

Your lecturer sounds like a sadist to me.  What would be the objection to checking your results against results obtained by reliable programs?

I'd ask if I could write a computer program to do it instead of doing it manually.  It'll take time, but not nearly as much as doing it by hand.

Here’s the thing. I am currently in the process of writing my thesis, and the thesis regulations set by my advisor (the lecturer I mentioned earlier) require me to understand both the programming and manual methods. So, when there is a proposal or research result seminar, I will be tested by having to present it through Python Pandas code with an understanding by explaining the flow through manual calculations, because in the code there are manual calculations at work. Therefore, manual calculations are a must.

Are there any statistics professors you know of who are open to discussing STL Decomposition? If so, could I please request their contact information? I really need it. Thank you in advance. @whuber

"Manual" seems to mean "have the human being carry out the instructions in the computer program you have already written."  Maybe you do have to do that, to prove you can add and multiply and follow mechanical instructions--who am I to criticize your thesis requirements?--but now we are far from anything of interest to a statistician or researcher!
